How to apply sensitivity curve to acoustic data
I have an underwater sound signal obtained from a hydrophone in "Counts", of the order of ~10^7. Here is a slice of it :

The manufacturer gave me a frequency response correction function giving, for each frequency, a correction to apply to the raw data (in dB re 1 $\mu$Pa/Count). This is supposed to account for frequency-dependent sensitivity/gain. Here is this transfer function :

Suppose we trust this transfer function. How may I use all of this to get an absolute $\mu$Pa time series ?

I guess it depends on what the conversion factor given by the manufacturer corresponds to. In many cases, microphone manufacturers provide some frequency response correction curve for their equipment to be applied to measured data. In other cases, manufacturers provide the frequency or impulse response of their equipment (you can easily reach through the other via the Fourier transform), in which case you have to invert it. Whether you do it with correction or response curves you usually have to multiply (frequency domain) or convolve (time domain) the signal with the correction.

See this answer in case it helps somehow.

@ZaellixA thanks for the link, but it deals with homogeneous sensitivity while here it depends on frequency. For your other comment, your last point is indeed what I am looking for, I edit the question to be clear about the case

a) Can you post a link to the data sheet? b) that sounds like 2 separate questions: "how do I convert counts to Pa" and "how do I apply a frequency dependent calibration".

@Hilmar a) what would be the use of a such object ? I think the question can remain abstract, the context is simple, do not hesitate to ask for clarification if it isn't b) I edit a bit the question, the idea is that to get basolute Pa I theoretically need a sensitivity, which here is the frequency-dependent correction

@Asimonu: something feels off here, Typically sensitivity drops at high and low frequencies but you calibration curve looks the other way around. Also the numbers are VERY large. In the midband this is supposed to be 70 dB re 1uPa/count. 1e7 counts gained up by 70 dB would result in 30 kPa. That's over 180 dB SPL  or about 1/3 atmospheric pressure. These pressure levels are rarely found outside the launch pad of  Saturn V rocket.  What order of magnitude are you expecting? Is the curve somehow upside down ?

@Asimonu: Do you have the calibration curve as numerical data or just as a graph?

@Hilmar Thanks for your feedbacks. The curve I gave is also available as numerical data (which I can easily interpolate), and is not the sensitivity curve but a correction function curve. As it is supposed to counter non-linear sensitivity, it indeed looks "reversed" compared to a normal sensitivity curve.
One thing I did not mention is that here, we are underwater. I did not mention it first because I wanted to formulate an abstract problem. I add it to the question.

1. Intro
I will try to ignore Hilmar’s comments, which are spot on, in order to provide an “educated possible solution”.
2. Straightforward answer
The “naive” solution would be to Fourier transform (via FFT) your signal to the frequency domain and then, simply, apply the correction/calibration provided by the manufacturer. One detail to consider when converting your data into the frequency domain is that you must divide by the length of your signal vector.
Additionally, you must ensure you have the correction/calibration value per frequency in your frequency domain vector. I see two options here. One is to ensure your frequency domain data vector is as long as the correction/calibration factors vector. The other is to interpolate the correction values vector to get as many values as elements in your data vector.
One final detail to consider is converting the correction/calibration data to linear values (counts). This should be straightforward, just by using the “dB-to-linear” conversion formula
$$ x_{lin} = 10^{y_{dB}/10} \tag{1} $$
Then, you can apply the correction/calibration to your frequency domain data and convert it back to dB if this is what you’d like to achieve.
Remarks
Just as Hilmar suggested in their comments, you should be extra careful and approach the problem with caution and scepticism. The values you show in your plots are quite large, and they don’t seem to resemble the “known” behaviour of most converters. Make sure to double-check your results. Or, even better, troubleshoot your apparatus by applying a signal of known sound level (using a calibrator would be ideal, as it is also considered “best practice”) and then check your results against that known value.
